# What exactly does Overflow:hidden does in this program?

Tags: css

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.header {
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
}
.footer {
    background-color: #444;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
}
.topmenu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #777;
}
.topmenu li {
    float: left;
}
.topmenu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.topmenu li a:hover {
    background-color: #222;
}
.topmenu li a.active {
    color: white;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
.sidemenu {
    width: 25%;
}
.content {
    width: 75%;
}
.sidemenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.sidemenu li a {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #eee;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
}
.sidemenu li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
.sidemenu li a.active {
    background-color: #008CBA;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="topmenu">
  <li><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="column sidemenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#flight">The Flight</a></li>
      <li><a href="#city" class="active">The City</a></li>
      <li><a href="#island">The Island</a></li>
      <li><a href="#food">The Food</a></li>
      <li><a href="#people">The People</a></li>
      <li><a href="#history">The History</a></li>
      <li><a href="#oceans">The Oceans</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="column content">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>The City</h1>
    </div>
    <h1>Chania</h1>
    <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
    <p>You will learn more about responsive web pages in a later chapter.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer Text</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I compiled this program without overflow:hidden and it wasn't giving the same output,I can't understand why overflow:hidden is necessary here?   I even used overflow:auto and it doesnt show scroll so I know that it isn't that the box is too small for data. It is present in the top menu.
I am a newbiee to CSS and it is really confusing for me that why do they have two classes for some elements, why do they use box-sizing,
And please edit if there is any problem with the way I have
asked,because downvoting it prohibits me from  asking questions and
- renders me helpless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an experienced CSS user, and this took a while for me to find.  The `.topbar` element is a `ul` without a defined height, and so it looks to child elements to determine the height.  However, as your elements inside are using `float`, the parent is not resized.

As [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751296/ul-height-when-containing-floating-li) discusses, `overflow: none`, is a hack to solve this problem.  However, I don't think this is the best approach in your case. I would either:

1. Define a constant height for your topbar
2. Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead of `ul`

Comment: What is a child element?

Comment: I thank you,But please can you elaborate about the use of overflow:hidden.

Comment: @Therebelentropy `overflow:hidden` is designed to hide any content which is not within the area of an element.  It is extremely counter-intuitive that it works in this way (read the comments in the previous answer).  As you will learn, CSS is less science than art.