# CSS floated button jumps out of the wrapper division

Tags: html, css

The problem i am facing with floated div is i have written this piece of code:

[CodePiece1](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ecq2/1/)

but whenever i try add the class ;right' ,that makes it float to the right, to the button it jumps out of the wrapper div as

[CodePiece2](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ecq2/2/)

How can i keep the left floated button inside the wrapper div rather then it being out of the wrapper div as in case of the second code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to the `#buttonWrapper`.

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ecq2/8/**

Comment: Thanks a lot.Can you please explain it too.

Comment: floated elements don't have a fixed location so parent elements can be unsure what to do with them. setting overflow to hidden forces the element to work out what size it is, therefore including the location of floated child elements, fixing your problem

Comment: @deXter Here is an StackOverflow answer that explains it better than I ever could: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3416217/681807

Comment: isn't overflow:hidden supposed to hide content overflowing out of the div block?

Comment: @deXter It does, but as mentioned by SmokeyPHP it also forces the element to extend to an appropriate size to fit the floating child elements. You can use `overflow: auto` if you wish but I find that sometimes causes scroll bars to appear. Check out [this link](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/) about the CSS Overflow property and navigate down to the "Float Clearing" section.

Comment: Thanks - A lifesaver for a CSS noob :-)

Answer (score 2):

Add the style:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

to #buttonWrapper or #updateWrapper