# Positioning layers inside layers, wrapper doesn't wrap around the other contained layers

Tags: css, html, wrapper, layer

Dear community members,

I am actually a bit new to CSS, however I know my way around after a two weeks of studying. However at the moment I have a small problem with layers (div-tags) that I can't seem to fix. The problem is as follow, I have created the following to demonstrate my problem.

```
<body style="margin: 0;">
  <div style="margin: 0px auto; width: 960px;" id="main">
    <div style="clear: both; float: left; width: 100%; height: 100px;" id="one">
      Hello World
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both; float: left; width: 100%; height: 200px;" id="two">
      Hello next World!
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The problem here is, if you "look at the borders" (I have removed; background-color and border property to increase the readability of the code), you will notice that the first main div doesn't wrap around div one and two. If I want to fix it, I only have to add some contents to the main layer. resulting in the following code:

```
<body style="margin: 0;">
  <div style="margin: 0px auto; width: 960px;" id="main">
    <div style="clear: both; float: left; width: 100%; height: 100px;" id="one">
      Hello World
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both; float: left; width: 100%; height: 200px;" id="two">
      Hello next World!
    </div>
  LET ME SOLVE IT!
  </div>
</body>
```

The question now is, how do I get the last result without adding "just contents" to my main layer?

Thank you very much for reading my question and answering it!

For images please see: http://www4.picturepush.com/photo/a/7808622/img/7808622.png and http://www3.picturepush.com/photo/a/7808636/img/7808636.png

(NOTE: all are direct links ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add overflow:hidden to your container div.  This will force the div to 'wrap' around your inner divs.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Also, divs are block elements by default, so there is no need to add width:100% to your inner divs, as they will stretch to fit their parent div (960px) already.

Comment: I got a question, can you explain why actually this happens? Thank you for the warm welcome, I really appreciate your response!

Comment: Heh, good question.  You can find an explanation in this answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400749/how-does-css-overflowhidden-work-to-force-an-element-containing-floated-elem  but it's a little hard to wrap your head around.    By the way, if you liked my answer and found it useful, perhaps you might consider marking it as the accepted answer so I can get a little SO rep juice.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake
Add a clear div  an put it as the last div inside your wrapper.
Also, avoid using percentages for your width, if your wrapper has a fixed with then use fixed width for your inner divs.
Hope this helps!