# Can someone explain me why isn't <article>'s size correct and how to fix it?

Tags: html, css

http://zergxost.com/test.html

As you can see, if there's not enough text, the bottom gray line goes way higher than it should. Can someone please explain why doesn't "article"'s hitbox include the "header"? And how ti fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code on here. We should not have to search your site for what you are referring to. It may also be helpful to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows the problem.

Comment: Quick note - I can't set min-height because the header is always different in height and content.

Comment: Okay: http://jsfiddle.net/DwarfVader/NacvS/  My webpage is actually pretty small, but if this makes it easier for you, then sure, here it is :P

Comment: @DwarfVader - Providing a JSFiddle is just a good way to "future proof" your post on StackOverflow. That way if your site moves or changes in the future, people will still be able to refer back to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a either a `overflow: hidden` or a `clear: left` declaration. You should always clear floating objects or declare overflow to be hidden (carefully!).

```
article {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or:

```
div#wrapper div.related {
  width: 100%;
  height: 960px;
  border-top: 1px solid #808080;
  margin-top: 20px;
  clear: left;
}
```

#### Why/how `overflow: hidden` works

When you set a block-level element to have `overflow: hidden`, you're actually telling the browser change how it handles block elements. Functionally, you told the browser to contain normal elements (including floated ones). Things that will exceed the total dimensions of the box, usually by relative/absolute positioning, or images with huge widths, will get clipped to the wrapper's width. Drop down regions that cross over a container with `overflow: hidden` may cause them to get clipped as they enter as well.

Elements at the end of a `overflow: hidden` container will also have padding-bottom and margin-bottom applied.

Another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3416217/24950

Comment: Thank you! Yes, clear:left; worked for me. I shall learn about clears and floats, it seems.

Comment: I should have mentioned the option of using `overflow:hidden;` as well.  Good call, Robert!

Comment: @DwarfVader Try the `overflow: hidden` declaration too. It can "contain" a float, but can cause issues when an element is floating over top of it (with `position: absolute`). But both have good uses.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks. It does have it's occasional quirks though.

Comment: Yes, they do! And I utilizing both already. A little question, though (if I may) - what exactly does overflow:hidden; do in this occasion? Why doesn't it cut off the header?

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear `div#wrapper div.related`.  Try adding the following to your CSS:

```
div#wrapper div.related {
    clear: both;
}
```