# CSS Float does not stretch Div Height

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have had this problem for a long time when working with HTML/CSS and Floats.

In the image you can see I have a Box Div that is Floated left as there is many of these Boxes.  Inside the Box I have a `<UL>` List.  The List items `<li>` are also Floated left.

As you can see in the image, the List items do not make the Box Div that they are inside of Expand.  I have tried several thing without much luck and was hoping someone with more experience could help?  I cannot set a fixed height on the Box Div as the number of icons is always different and it needs to expand to fix them.

[image]

Live demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/u5HXu/

```
<div class="module-box">
    <div class="module-box-title">
        <h4><i class="icon-cogs"></i>Admin Settings</h4>
        <div class="tools">
            <a href="#" class="collapse">-</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="module-box-body" style="display: block;">


        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://cp.codedevelopr.com/modules/password_assistant/assets/icon.png" border="0">
                    <span class="module-icon password_assistant"></span>
                </a><br>
                <a href="#">Change<br>Password</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://cp.codedevelopr.com/modules/password_assistant/assets/icon.png" border="0">
                    <span class="module-icon password_assistant"></span>
                </a><br>
                <a href="#">Change<br>Password</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://cp.codedevelopr.com/modules/password_assistant/assets/icon.png" border="0">
                    <span class="module-icon password_assistant"></span>
                </a><br>
                <a href="#">Change<br>Password</a>
            </li>
        </ul>


    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Modules homepage */
.module-box {
    margin: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    width: 464px;
}

.module-box-title {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 8px 10px 2px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 51px;
    line-height: 45px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

.module-box-title h4 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.module-box-title .tools {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 6px;
    float: right;
}
.module-box-title .tools a {
    font-size: 31px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 29px;
}

.module-box-body {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    clear: both;
}

.module-box-body a {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #888;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.module-box-body li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 12px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to clear your floats using a clearfix or clearing element.

**Method #1 clearfix**

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Then you add the class on the containing element

```
 <div class="module-box-body clearfix" style="display: block;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u5HXu/8/

**Method #2 Clearing Element**

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Then you add the following HTML after your floated elements.

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u5HXu/9/

Comment: **Note:** Method #2 is more cross-browser compatible (older versions), but also less desirable since it adds HTML that does not have any semantic usefulness whatsoever.

Comment: Method #1 known support: Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+, Chrome, Opera 9+, IE 6+ http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `overflow: hidden` trick on the parent container (..module-box-body) ;) fixes everything.

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/ct6gr/

Comment: @wrongstars It's hard to explain it in layman's terms, but basically using `overflow: hidden` establishes a new block flow context, which forces the parent container to "recognize" and sequester the inner floated element entirely. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400749/how-does-css-overflowhidden-work-to-force-an-element-containing-floated-elem

Comment: @Terry, dude, this is exactly what i was looking for, it's ridiculous how simple this answer is to solve the issue at hand. Are you a magician ?

Answer (score 2):

Change your `.module-box-body li` to

```
.module-box-body li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 12px 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5HXu/6/).

Answer (score 1):

Try applying `overflow:auto` to the container, the one whose height you want to resize based on the height of its contents (the floated items).

I'd add a jsfiddle link but it's not been working *at all* for me recently.  :/