# css div is not expanding to fit imaged floated

Tags: html, css

I have a div and I want to keep an image on the right of it.

The problem is that the div is not expanding to fit the image. I gave the div a background to check that.

This is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BJ7YZ/

very simple code

#### What I have tried

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122949/css-float-does-not-stretch-div-height)

and I tried to do the same. I gave the `div .header` class a clear class, which is:

```
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

and I gave the div that contains the image, which is `.logo_container` this fix:

```
.logo_container:after, .logo_container::before {
    clear: both;
}
```

none of them has worked. **I know the problem is because I didn't set a height to the `.header`, but I need to not set the height.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried giving `display: inline-block;` to your header class? It seems to do the trick. I can see the red background by applying it.

Comment: +1 to your efforts, but the `overflow:auto` seems to be the good answer.

Comment: This also works, and so does `display: table` and `display: inline-table`, these, along with `dislay: inline-block`, also create new block-formatting contexts.

Comment: @MarcAudet is this `display` better than the `overflow` pelase? i think so, right?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Equivalent yes, better?, depends a bit on what needs to be done.  Most of the time, it depends on how well you need to support legacy browsers and so on.

Comment: @MarcAudet do you imply that `inline-block` is not supported by allow browsers?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I was thinking of using pseudo-elements to generate clearing elements, some older browsers don't support pseudo-elements, but that is not as big an issue as it was 10 years ago. Also, early versions of IE did not support inline-blocks very well.

Answer (score 3):

One way of taking care of this problem is as follows:

```
.header{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Adding `overflow: auto` creates a new block formatting context and the floated child elements are confined within the edges of the parent container.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/zptjb/

Comment: +1 to your efforts, but is this `overflow:auto` better than the answer by `@Alex` ?

Comment: please when I did that, a new scroll appears, how to remove it please?

Comment: That is the problem with using overflow when things do actually overflow. You can use `overflow: hidden;` too, as long as you don't want anything visible outside of the content area.

Comment: @Alex `hidden` is not a good solution, what I did is removing the `top:10 and right 10` and adding `margin-top and margin-righ` to the `logo_container`, and it works

Comment: Excellent question.  If you use postion: relative to offset your image, you are causing the image to extend beyond the bounding box of the parent, so you see an overflow.  You could add margins to the image container and get the same positioning.  The scroll bar is because of the `overflow: auto`.  In contrast, if you use inline-blok (solution by @Alex), you see the image jutting out but no scoll bar since the overflow is simply visible but scroll bars are not emanbled.

Comment: The various proposed solutions here all have nuances even though they basically do the same thing.  The best one depends on the subtleties of how you need to position and style your content.

Comment: @MarcAudet in my opinion, using a `display:inline-block` is better than the `overflow` but you write @Alex, you mean @IndieRok ?

Comment: Yes, misread the page... @IndieRok posted about inline-block.

Comment: @MarcAudet I am sorry, I have selected `@IndieRok's` answers, I wish I could choose many answers. Many thanks for your great efforts

Comment: You are very welcome, your courtesy is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the container itself. The easiest way today is to use this lovely, simple, clearfix "hack". See updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/BJ7YZ/2/

and

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

```
.header:before,
.header:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.header:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: is this way better than `overflow:auto` ? please? +1 to your efforts

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli No. Overflow:auto is better. Its not a hack and will work in older browsers as well.

Comment: Always forget the simple things. The link does have a further section to support older browsers though.