# how to float image to left that other doesn't go below it?

Tags: html, css

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BYnLd/1/)**

Can I accomplish this without touching html?

html...

```
    <div>
    <img src="http://i50.tinypic.com/1zey0j8.gif" alt="" />WALLPAPER
     <span>some paragraph here 
some paragraph here          /*this should not go below the image*/
some paragraph here 
some paragraph here
</span>
    </div>
```

csss...

```
div{width: 200px;}
img{float: left; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
span{display: block;}
```

**Edit**

**Kaloyan Ivanov** has given me a best answer. But I would like to know how overflow hidden do the trick?

Comment: Change the span to: `span{display: block; float:left; width:150px}` http://jsfiddle.net/BYnLd/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the span.

http://jsfiddle.net/BYnLd/2/

Answer (score 1):

As you may not know what height below the image would be. So use `margin-bottom: 100%;` to your image

**[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BYnLd/6/)**

**Edit**

As Edited question, I am providing you a link for that

[How does CSS 'overflow:hidden' work to force an element (containing floated elements) to wrap around floated elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400749/how-does-css-overflowhidden-work-to-force-an-element-containing-floated-elem)

Answer (score 0):

Give your image a bottom margin like:

```
img {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BYnLd/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You should float the span element also to the left. And make sure that it has a maximum width of 150px.

CSS should look something like this:

```
div{width:200px;}
img{float:left; width:50px;height:50px;}
span{display:block; width:140px; padding-left:10px;}
```