# background color disappears when overflow is visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following `CSS` code written;

```
#container {
    width: 1300px;
    background-color:green;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#menu {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

After searching  google for a long time I couldn't find an explaination why the container *background color* is disappearing when the container `overflow` attribute is *visible*.

Can someone help me understand why ?

---

### Update:

---

Thanks alot for your answers.... :)

I don't mind using overflow:hidden, ijust want to understand its purpose and how to use it.

As i unserstand, the overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box, so i dont understand why would its visibilty make the container background color disappear or why would it change the container height.

Comment: show html markup too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the elements within the container are have `float:left` - the container had a height of 0 - which is also what is causing you not to see any background.

In order to fix this there are a few solutions out there:

One of them is called clearfix

```
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
  <!-- floated elements here -->
</div>

.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Another is by setting `overflow:hidden` on the container element - this establishes a new block formatting context - which in effect clears the floats. (See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400749/how-does-css-overflowhidden-work-to-force-an-element-containing-floated-elem))

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting):

> Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers (such as
>   inline-blocks, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block
>   boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (except
>   when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish new
>   block formatting contexts for their contents.
>
> > In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other,
> >     vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block. The vertical
> >     distance between two sibling boxes is determined by the 'margin'
> >     properties. Vertical margins between adjacent block-level boxes in a
> >     block formatting context collapse.
> >
> > In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the
> >     left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right
> >     edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats (although a
> >     box's line boxes may shrink due to the floats), unless the box
> >     establishes a new block formatting context (in which case the box
> >     itself may become narrower due to the floats).

Comment: Thanks Danield... Just to make sure i understand ....

By setting overflow:hidden on the container element, i'm making the container "see" the floted boxes as non floated elements?

Comment: @Joe Read this post [How does the CSS Block Formatting Context work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6196725/703717)  - it should clear things up

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the floating child element. If your container only contains floated elements, its height will be equal to zero.

You need to include a clear element, different possibilities exists:

- **The Empty Div Method**: By adding a `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` as latest child element.
- **The Overflow Method**: By setting an `overflow: hidden` on the container element
- **The Easy Clearing Method**: By adding extra CSS and a class on the parent element (`clearfix'`)

  .clearfix:after { 
     content: "."; 
     visibility: hidden; 
     display: block; 
     height: 0; 
     clear: both;
  }

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you have not given any height to `#menu`.

As, `#container` has height of `#menu`, background is not visible.

Give some height to it.

```
#menu {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    background-color: yellow;
    height:50px;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/k36AQ/)

Comment: I tried it... I wrote your code and deleted the "overflow:hidden" attribute from the container... but unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of the container div to be equal with the height of the menu. This way you don't need the overflow: hidden setting.

```
$("#container").height($("#menu").height());
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/er144/ZV6pb/