# Auto set height of DIV without JQuery

Tags: html, css

I have two `div` elements. Second is inside in first element. 
In second I display some text. For second `div` I set height to auto and when I put more text in `div` height is greater. Also I set height for first `div` to auto, but first `div` has always same height.

How I can set height of `DIV` to be dependable of number of text rows?

```
<div class="first-div">
  <div class="second-div">
  </div>
</div>

.first-div {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #b8b8b8;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 75px;
}
.second-div {
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
    font-size: 9px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` to `.first-div`.

You may want to check out this question: [How does CSS 'overflow:hidden' work to force an element (containing floated elements) to wrap around floated elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400749/how-does-css-overflowhidden-work-to-force-an-element-containing-floated-elem)

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/shhxvxgh/)**

add `overflow: auto` to outer div (.first-div)

css

```
.first-div {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #b8b8b8;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 75px;
    overflow:auto; /* added */
}
.second-div {
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
    font-size: 9px;
    height: auto;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/shhxvxgh/1/)

or you can add div to the html and set its style as `clear: both`

css

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

html

```
<div class="first-div">
  <div class="second-div"></div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `min-height` from your `.first-div` and apply `overflow: hidden` check out the fiddle, I think this is what you want.

In the `.second-div` you can change the height with `min-height`. In the fiddle I have it at 300px.

http://jsfiddle.net/wcnbq9xc/