# Getting images to fit into white box and not float outside of it

Tags: html, css

How would I go about getting the images on my gallery page into the white box?

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uuLk4uyq/

**HTML**

```
<section class="mainSection" style="width: 100%">
    <h1>Gallery</h1>
    <article class="content">
        <h2>Gallery</h2>
        <ul class="photos">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_120_120/p/7/005/011/058/355e0d5.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_120_120/p/7/005/011/058/355e0d5.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_120_120/p/7/005/011/058/355e0d5.jpg" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding

```
overflow: hidden;
```

on

```
.content
```

put the images on your gallery page into the white box.

Some issues may arise with `overflow: hidden;`. Like when items outside of that div are hidden or cut off.

Alternativally, you could add `<div class="clear"></div>` after the last `li` along with:

```
.clear{
  clear:both
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uuLk4uyq/1/)

A better solution is to add the `.clearfix` on `.content`. You don't need the extra markup.

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uuLk4uyq/2/)

What is a [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)?

Learn more on http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: Nice one with the `overflow: hidden`. How does that work? Didn't strike me as a logic solution.

Comment: @JimmyRare I did not know why. I knew that worked!. Found a explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400749/how-does-css-overflowhidden-work-to-force-an-element-containing-floated-elem

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to add display: inline-block on .content

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stretch that white part over your images:

```
.content {
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 3% 5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```