# CSS Overflow Issue (with Navigation bar)

Tags: css, html-lists, overflow, navigationbar

I am currently learning CSS and currently I get stuck on "overflow". 
Here are the codes that I am practicing. I do not understand why when I turn it to overflow: visible, then the webpage will turn to be white? Why is it the case? I have tried all other possible solutions on overflow, like auto, scroll. They all works the way I expect, but not the case of visible? Can anyone explain to me why is it the case?

In my css,

```
        * {
            color: white;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #horizontal_bar {
            background-color: black;
            overflow: hidden; /* When I change it to overflow: visible; the webpage turns white, why is it the case? */
            margin-top: 2em;
        }

        #horizontal_bar ul li{
            list-style-type: none;
            float: left;
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        #horizontal_bar ul li img {
            height: 12px;
        }

        #horizontal_bar ul li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 5px 20px;
            height: 12px;
        }

        a:focus, a:hover {
            background-color: gray;
        }

        #content {
            clear: left;
        }
```

In my HTML,

```
<body>
    <div id="horizontal_bar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" >HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="" >CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="" >JAVASCRIPT</a></li>
                <li><a href="" >SQL</a></li>
                <li><a href="" >PHP</a></li>
                <li><a href="" >jQuery</a></li>
                <li><a href="" ><img src="images/search2.png" alt="search"/></a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here are the 2 screenshots I have captured. The first one is the case, when I set overflow attribute as hidden, and the later one is the case when I set overflow attribute as visible. 
[image: overflow: hidden]
[image: overflow: visible]

Hope to have a nice explanation on why it is the case when overflow = visible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner `li` have `float:left`, which cause the outer elements to loss its dimension. Outer element need either `float` or `overflow` specified to make them grow and contain the inner floating elements.

Not only `overflow:hidden`, some other value like `auto` and `overlay` will also make the div grow.

A div is `overflow:visible` by default. So it dosen't have any effect.

There is already an answer here - [how-does-css-overflowhidden-work-to-force-an-element-containing-floated-elem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400749/how-does-css-overflowhidden-work-to-force-an-element-containing-floated-elem)

Comment: Its really useful. +1 for your search terms

Comment: thanks... 
with the idea you have suggested, I have been browsing more on float, and find this link particular useful. 
[link] (https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `height` property along with `overflow` to get expected output.

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ahfuz2m7/)**

```
#horizontal_bar {
    background-color: black;
    height:34px;
    overflow: visible;      
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

For more info about `overflow` refer **[MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)**

Comment: Not strictly true. I have overflow auto layouts with no height specifications anywhere on the page. You can test this with eg:

Comment: position: absolute; overflow: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0

Comment: @NevilleHillyer: I mentioned only for op's code, not in general.. there are so many ways to get op's expected output, i just give one of them

Comment: My previous comment was about the unfortunate, although often stated, necessity of a height specification for satisfactory overflow operation.

Answer (score 0):

> Paste this
>
> ## horizontal_bar {
>
> ```
> background-color: black;
> float: left;
> margin-top: 2em;
> overflow: visible;
> position: relative;
> width: 100%; }
> ```